# Почему не рестартится apache после активации модуля SSL (Debian)?

Tags: debian, ssl, apache2

После того, как активирую SSL:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

рестарт апача вызывает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если делаю:

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
```

то все работает нормально.

Comment: Читайте лог ошибок

Comment: Вам системд советует журнал глянуть на вашем скрине

Comment: @Hellseher я его как раз и распечатал

Comment: `journalctl -xe` там указано